# How can trigger onNotification when app in background React Native Firebase

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am investigating about React Native and Firebase Cloud Messaging. In the document, I see that has 2 types of message can be send to client is:

- `Notification message ( Or Notification and data message )`
- `Data - only message`

The first one can be trigger by client using `onNotification`, and it only trigger if the app on foreground, if in background no way to trigger that has a notification. Just `onNotificationOpened` can be fired.

The second is inverse, the app can trigger on foreground and background. In case the app has been closed/swiped, on Android luckily it can be triggered also by using a Handler background. But on iOS if the app closed/swiped that no way until we open app again.

The problem is what type of 2 message above that I can use to listen the notification coming, and how it can work if app in foreground, background and closed. 
Hope someone can help me about this.